# how to hide "All sites in this tab will be opened in internet explorer mode" in Edge with IE Mode?

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-chromium

I have create C# application to to launch MSEDGE.exe in IE mode using command line switch.

```
        ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        processInfo.FileName = "msedge";                
        StringBuilder arguments = new StringBuilder();                
        arguments.Append(" --ie-mode-force");
        arguments.Append(" --internet-explorer-integration=iemode");
        arguments.Append(" --no-first-run");
        arguments.Append(" --no-service-autorun");
        arguments.Append(" --disable-sync");
        arguments.Append(" --test-type");              
        arguments.Append(" --disable-features=msImplicitSignin");
        arguments.Append(" --user-data-dir=" + getEdgeTempFolder());
        arguments.Append(" www.google.com");
        processInfo.Arguments = arguments.ToString();              
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = processInfo;
        process.Start();
```

The above code will launch Microsoft Edge with IE mode. but when the page is displayed it will also display information bar on the top with "All sites in this tab will be opened in internet explorer mode".
How can i hide this information bar when it launch through any command line switch ?

this is the image of launching Edge with IE mode.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you are launching the MS Edge browser in the IE mode, it will display the information bar with the text "**All sites in this tab will be opened in internet explorer mode**" along with the IE browser logo beside the Address bar.

Based on my experience, there is no way to hide that information bar and IE logo.

If your C# application is accessing the site in the IE mode of the MS Edge browser then the users should know that they are seeing the site in the IE mode.